Error when sending POST request to post mapping; Spring Boot
I tried sending this in POSTMAN:
{
    "title": "the",
    "type": "MCQ",
    "teacher_id": "2",
    "questions" : [{
    "content": "Who are you",
    "answers":[{
        "content": "you",
        "correct" : "true"
    }]
  }],
    "status": "OPEN"
}


Tried switching media types but it didn't work, I couldn't send anything to that mapping successfully, I think it might have to do with the questions list that also has an answers list.
Get the error: "error": "Unsupported Media Type", "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

Here's the entity:

package com.academy.exams.entity;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Exam")
public class Exam {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "exam_id")
    private Long examId;

    private String title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ExamType type;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exam", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> questions;

    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private Long teacherId;

    private String status;

    public Long getId() {
        return examId;
    }

    public void setId(Long examId) {
        this.examId = examId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ExamType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ExamType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public Long getTeacherId() {
        return teacherId;
    }

    public void setTeacherId(Long teacherId) {
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Exam initialized");
    }
}


Here's the service, knowing I used this @Repository public interface ExamRepository extends JpaRepository<Exam, Long> {}:

 public Exam CreateExam(Exam exam){

        return examRepository.save(exam);
    }


And here's the controller:

package com.academy.exams.controller;
import com.academy.exams.entity.Exam;
import com.academy.exams.service.ExamService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/exams")

public class ExamController {

    @Autowired
    private ExamService examService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Exam createExam(@RequestBody Exam exam){
        return examService.CreateExam(exam);
    }
}


Here's the question Entity too:

package com.academy.exams.entity;
import com.academy.exams.entity.Exam;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")

public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
    private Exam exam;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    public Long getId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Exam getExam() {
        return exam;
    }

    public void setExam(Exam exam) {
        this.exam = exam;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}



And the answers entity:

package com.academy.exams.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Answer")

    public class Answer {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name ="answer_id")
        private Long answerId;

        private String content;

        @Column(name="correct")
        private Boolean correct;

        @JsonManagedReference
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "question_id" )
        private Question question;

        public Long getId() {
            return answerId;
        }

        public void setId(Long answerId) {
            this.answerId = answerId;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public Boolean getCorrect() {
            return correct;
        }

        public void setCorrect(Boolean correct) {
            this.correct = correct;
        }
    }




Please check HTTP header's content-type value in Postman configuration.

It's application/json

This error happens. "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'". This is because of cycle dependency between Exam and Question(also Question and Answer). I think you should fix two things.

Do not use entity in controller layer directly. Follow the layered architecture and avoid tightly coupling amongst layers.
Remove cycle dependency if it is not necessary.


For 1.I'm not sure how to do it, I've made it work before for an entity in all sorts of mapping in the controller by using it directly but it didn't have any lists of other entities.

I had to use @ManagedReference to avoid infinite loops.


About @ManagedReference annotaiton. Yes, you did but cycle dependency is bad pattern because two entities tightly coupled. Some changes one of them effect to other. That is why I recommended avoiding cycle if it is not necessary.

It's general good advice to layer different parts of the lifecycle, of your data. Therefore, in regular restful-web services, you shall at least define a specialized datatype for transfer (dto) and the persisted entity. It's much easier to debug different layers of your code, if lifecycles are strongly encapsulated.
I assume, for debugging purposes and to strengthen the extensibility and readability, you shall foremost define a distinct dto and persisted entity.
Since your problem relates to the rest-layer of your application, I won't review the jakarta persistence layer and leaf the focus.
I have tried to call your endpoint with my swagger-ui, getting the same error.

I assume, that with your approach of designing the dtos like tables of a database, we do shoot ourselves into our knees. Therefore, we could find a way to parse multiple shifting of json into valid Java Objects; but I think it's more wisely to reduce them as much as possible.
In the result, you will have to much more calls on rest endpoints, but each will be much more testable, encapsulated and reusable.
From my view of perspective, you are dealing with several use-cases, that shall be managed by your single endpoint:

Saving exams.
Mapping Questions to their exams.
Mapping Answers to their Questions.
Mapping teachers, to their exams (and vice versa).
Mapping the status of an exam, to their status.
List item.
[...]

In my daily business as backend-developer, I would provide for each use-case an separate rest-endpoint. Each tested by unit and/or integration-tests, derived from behavior driven development papers.
As a result, the ExamDto is reduced to:
public class ExamDto {

    private Long examId;

    private String title;

    private String type;
}

The "/exam/create" endpoint will only save exams. Other use-cases will be served by several, specialized and tested dto`s. As well as other rest-endpoints. But since you don't want to debug three layers of JSON-parsing (as me as well), this is now in your hands.

So I should create DTO's for all my entities, or the lists within or could I just get away with a separation of calls?

You shall not design your rest-api by more than three nesting layers of json. If you leave your dto's as atomic as possible, while encapsulating the design of your database from the design of your api (and vice versa), you might get much more likely testable code, without those errors.

This is one of the answers. Using @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation. I changed entity relationship like this. Ignore property when json decoding.
Exam
@Entity
@Table(name = "Exam")
public class Exam {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "exam_id")
    private Long examId;

    private String title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ExamType type;

    @JsonBackReference // this is changed
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exam", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> questions;

    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private Long teacherId;

    private String status;

    // getter, setters
}

Question
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("exam") // this is added
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @JsonManagedReference // this is changed
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
    private Exam exam;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    // getter, setters
}

Answer
@Entity
@Table(name = "Answer")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("question") // this is added
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    private Long answerId;

    private String content;

    @Column(name = "correct")
    private Boolean correct;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    // getter, setters
}

I can get request body like this.

I already commented about the cycle dependency. It makes your implementation difficult more and more when your business logic becomes complicated.

I've tried implementing your answer, but I can't populate the exam with the questions and answers at the same time, maybe I shouldn't?
I also couldn't list everything in the exam(questions, answers) in a GET mapping by using your suggestions where I could before.
